# Single point in R

Tags: r, point, coordinates

My question might be very simple. I want to create a single point (with xy coordinates) in a specific region, in a specific position. I don't want to do that with qgis I want to do that in R. Is there way? until now i  had created  a point with q and just copied the coordinates of it in R.
[image]

Comment: What is the context? There are different ways to plot a point, depending on the context.

Comment: I want to create a point from which I will draw a path. It will be my starting point and as you see I want it in specific position.

Comment: On a raster? On a basic plot?

Comment: on a vector bounding box from an area.

Comment: Could you provide some code? It is still not clear with which kind of data you are working with.

Comment: I am still working on my code. I want to do a pattern like the image for an area(bounding box), so I need to set coordinates for the first point. I have to define the position where the pattern starts.

Comment: Here is an `R` point, with my compliments: `c(1,2)`. I suspect it might not be satisfactory, but let it be a basis for exploring and improving your question: why might it fail to meet your requirements? What exactly do you mean by a "point" as an `R` data object? Exactly what restrictions should be applied to its coordinates to make it valid for your application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are pretty skinny on details (eg, should this be automated, what class object do you need, do you need attributes associated with the point, ...). The most straight forward answer is for you to use SpatialPoints to create an sp class point with no attributes. If you need attributes look at SpatialPointsDataFrame.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

# Create sp point object with no attributes
p <- SpatialPoints(cbind(-160,80))

# Create raster region, encompassing point
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

# Plot
plot(r)
plot(p,add=T,pch=20, cex=1.5)

# You could randomize the point by pulling the bounding box extent.
e <- bbox(r)                
p <- SpatialPoints(cbind(runif(1,e[1,]), runif(1,e[2,])))

# Plot
plot(r)
plot(p,add=T,pch=20, cex=1.5)
```